# Motion on the surface of a sphere without using the Energy Principle

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy-conservation, rotational-kinematics

> A smooth solid hemisphere is fixed with its plane face on a horizontal
>   table and its curved surface uppermost. The plane face of the
>   hemisphere has centre $O$ and radius $a$. The point $A$ is the highest
>   point on the hemisphere. A particle $P$ is placed on the hemisphere at
>   $A$. It is then given an initial horizontal speed $u$, where, $$  u^2
>  = \frac{1}{2}ga $$
>
> When $OP$ makes an angle $\theta$ with $OA$, and while $P$ remains on
>   the hemisphere, the speed of $P$ is $v$.
>
> Find an expression for $v^2$.

By using the conservation of energy principle, it is trivial to determine $v^2$ which is:

$$
v^2 = \frac{1}{2}ga(5-4\cos\theta)
$$

How do I derive the required result without using the energy principle?

Comment: Is this homework?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it, and any way you do it will basically be re-deriving conservation of energy.

**Notation:** I use $a$ for the radius of the sphere, $\vec{r}$ for the position of the object from the center of the sphere, $\vec{v}$ for the time derivative of $\vec{r}$, $\vec{F}$ for force, $g$ for gravitational acceleration, $N$ for the normal force, and all vectors with $\hat{\text{hats}}$ over them are of unit length.

We are concerned with the quantity $\vec{v}^2$, so consider the following truth from calculus:

$$\frac{d}{dt} m \vec{v}^2=2 m \vec{v} \cdot \vec{a}=2 \vec{v} \cdot \vec{F}$$

Then $$\vec{v}^2(T)=\frac{2}{m}\int_0^T \vec{v}(t)\cdot\vec{F}(t) dt+\vec{v}^2(0)$$

The constraint that the particle lies on a sphere is: $\vec{r}\cdot\vec{r}=a^2$. Differentiate this once with respect to time to get $\vec{v}\cdot \vec{r}=0$. But $\vec{F}$ is a linear combination of normal and gravitational forces: $\vec{F}=-mg\hat{z}+N\hat{r}$. So $\vec{v}\cdot\vec{F}=-mg \vec{v}\cdot\hat{z}=-mg\frac{d}{dt}(\vec{r}\cdot \hat{z})$. Apply the fundamental theorem of calculus:

$$\vec{v}^2(T)=-\frac{2mg}{m}\int_0^T \frac{d}{dt}\left(\vec{r}\cdot \hat{z}\right) dt=-2g\vec{r}(T)\cdot\hat{z}+2g\vec{r}(0)\cdot\hat{z}+\vec{v}^2(0)$$

Recognizing that $\vec{r}\cdot\hat{z}=a\cos(\theta)$, you have the original answer. $$\vec{v}^2(t)=2ga\left(\cos(\theta(0))-\cos(\theta(T))\right)+\vec{v}^2(0)$$

Plug in $\theta(0)=0$, $\theta(T)\equiv \theta$, $\vec{v}^2(0)=\frac{1}{2} ga$ to get your original answer.

All that we really did was prove that the time derivative of $\frac{1}{2}m v^2+mgz$ is zero, so we just proved conservation of energy for this system.

Answer (score 1):

The usual way:

1. write down all the forces (i.e. gravity and normal force in this case)
2. find the resulting force (which should depend on the position $\theta$ on the hemisphere and should be tangential to it)
3. using Newton's second law, write down the equation of motion
4. solve the equation of motion using  the given initial conditions.

Comment: The reason I posted this question is because I couldn't obtain it by your suggested method.